# How to make a multidimensional array comprehension in javascript?

Tags: javascript, list-comprehension

Given: `a = [[1,2],[3,4],]`

I want to do something like:

```
a = [for ([x,y] of a) [x*2,y]];
```

But this gives me the next error:

> 'SyntaxError: missing variable name'

I am able to do the following:

```
a = [for (z of a) [z[0]*2,z[1]]];
```

I prefer the first notation as the internal variables (x and y) can be given descriptive names making the code easier to read.  Is it possible?

Comment: Javascript is not Python.The `array comprehensions` is non-standard in Javascript. For future-facing usages, consider using Array.prototype.map, Array.prototype.filter, arrow functions, and spread syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `array` **comprehensions** is non-standard in Javascript. For future-facing usages, just use `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.filter`, `arrow functions`, and `spread syntax` features of `Javascript` language.

For this example, use `map` method which accepts as parameter a `callback` provided function.

```js
let a = [[1,2],[3,4]];
console.log(a.map(([x,y]) => [x*2, y]));
```

Comment: To answer my original question using maps I'd do:
`b = a.map(([x,y]) => [x*2, y])`

Thanks for your post.  I'll avoid array comprehensions!

Comment: @TimMahrt, yes..this is also one solution.